# Trying to pipe data from a child-process server to its parent process

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I'm working on an assignment for my Distributed Systems class. I'm a master's student in C.S., but my specialty in programming is .NET and I'm working on a project that requires some fairly involved Unix knowledge, which is tripping me up.

The assignment is implementing a flush channel protocol API. So I'm coding a small function library that other apps can implement to use flush channel communication. I've set it up so that when the init function is called, it forks a child process to act as the server for incoming messages. The child communicates with the parent process by sending incoming data to the parent through a pipe.

This works OK if messages are sent and received one at a time; e.g.,

send -> receive -> send -> receive -> etc.

However, if multiple messages are sent before doing any receives; e.g.,

send -> send -> send -> receive

then it gets messed up. Specifically, the first message is received correctly, but when I go to receive the second message, the program hangs and needs to be killed. I've done a lot of searching online and been plugging away at this for hours but haven't made much progress.

The program as a whole is far too large to show here, but here are the most relevant bits. Here's the part where I get the server going and receive messages. Note the line

write(fd[1], buffer, (strlen(buffer)+1));

-- I think that's a good candidate for being the source of the problem here, but not sure what to do differently. (Tried fwrite() and that didn't work at all.)

```
    fd = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    int nbytes;
    if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
        perror("Could not create pipe");
        return -1;
    }

    pID = fork();

    if (pID < 0) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
        return -1;
    } else if (pID == 0) { // child
        close(fd[0]);  // close input side of pipe
        int cc;
        int fsize;
        struct sockaddr_in from;
        int serials[500];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) serials[i] = 0;

        char buffer[2048];

        while (1) {
            fsize = sizeof(from);
            cc = recvfrom(socketNo, buffer, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fsize);
            if (cc < 0) perror("Receive error");
            datagram data = decodeDatagram(buffer);
            if (serials[data.serial] == 0) {
                write(fd[1], buffer, (strlen(buffer)+1));
                serials[data.serial] = 1;
            }
        }
    } else { // parent
        close(fd[1]);  // close output side of pipe
        return 0;
    }
```

(The "serials" array is for not forwarding repeated messages, as messages are sent multiple times to improve reliability. I know a fixed size for this array is not good practice, but the tests for this assignment don't send that many messages so it's OK in this context.)

The beginning of the receive function looks like this:

```
int fRecv(int* id, char* buf, int nbytes) {

    checkDatagramTable(*id);

    char* tbuf = malloc((nbytes + 9) * sizeof(char));
    int rbytes = read(fd[0], tbuf, nbytes + 9);
```

The "+9" is to accommodate additional information that gets packaged along with the message to be sent, for flush channel ordering. This is also a pretty sketchy area, but allocating more space to be extra sure has not helped the issue.

I know there's quite a bit of extraneous stuff in here, references to other functions etc. But the problem surely lies in how I'm piping the data through, so the source of my issue should lie there somewhere.

Thanks in advance for your assistance; it is truly appreciated.

Comment: You allocate a new `buffer` every trip through the `while(1)` loop -- why? I don't see why it is dynamically allocated rather than stack-allocated, and I don't see why it would persist outside this function.

Comment: Incidentally, `strace(1)` can be _really_ helpful when trying to track down problems. It's like a free `printf(3)` line on every system call.

Comment: I don't remember why I did it that way, but apparently there's a good reason because changing it to be stack-allocated causes the compiler to give some very ominous-looking warnings. Why? Do you think this is related to the problem I'm having?

Comment: I'm curious about the warnings you're getting -- but this shouldn't be the error that caught you, it is just a simple memory leak. You probably wouldn't even notice it for a few hundred thousand messages.

Comment: Turns out the warnings were due to me messing up the change. Editing code at 2:30 AM isn't such a good idea -- think I'm gonna go to bed and tackle this some more in the morning.

Comment: Oh yes, and thank you for the mention of strace(); if I don't get this working soon I think I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious. (what is in the packets? They could be binary) Where is the typedefinition for datagram ?

```
fsize = sizeof(from);
        cc = recvfrom(socketNo, buffer, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fsize);
        if (cc < 0) perror("Receive error");
        datagram data = decodeDatagram(buffer);
        if (serials[data.serial] == 0) {
            write(fd[1], buffer, (strlen(buffer)+1)); // <-- ????
            serials[data.serial] = 1;
        }
```

I'd try instead:

```
            write(fd[1], buffer, cc);
```

UPDATE:

If the message is not null terminated, you'll have to terminate it explicitly:

```
    (if cc == 2048) cc -= 1; 
    buffer [cc] = '\0'; // <<--
    datagram data = decodedatagram(buffer);
    ...
```

Also, it is advisable to use "sizeof buffer" instead of "2048".

UPDATE2:
You could test if the strings in the packets are **really** null-terminated by:

```
        unsigned pos;
        cc = recvfrom(socketNo, buffer, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fsize);
        if (cc < 0) perror("Receive error");
        for pos=0; pos < cc; pos++) {
             if (buff[pos] == 0) break;
             }
        switch (cc-pos) {
        case 0: fprintf (stderr, "No nul byte found in packet: I lose!\n" ); break;
        default: fprintf (stderr, "Spurious nul byte found in the middle of packet\n" );
        case 1: break;
             }

        datagram data = decodeDatagram(buffer);
        if (serials[data.serial] == 0) {
            write(fd[1], buffer, cc);
            serials[data.serial] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: The packets are guaranteed to be character data; that's part of the assignment description -- sorry, I should have specified that in my question. In any case, after changing it, its behavior is the same -- works fine when data is sent and received sequentially, but when a bunch of packets are sent at once before the user application goes to receive them, it hangs when attempting to retrieve the second packet.

Comment: They might be character, but are they null-terminated? Does the sender explicitly put a '\0' at the end of every packet? Besides: why *would* you call strlen() if you know the packets are null terminated?

Comment: Those are all good points but as I said, I changed the line to what you suggested and it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: You still did not answer the question "is the received ascii data null terminated" ? Anyway: I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why it was strlen + 1 instead of just strlen.

Comment: Hexdump the data on reception, just to be sure.